# How can I assign a specific id to the last comment of a post

Tags: comments

I am fairly new to Wordpress and I am currently designing a template for a client of our company. However, I need to assign a specific id to the last comment of a post.

Basically I have my own function that is called on the callback of `wp_list_comments()`.
this is due to the fact that I have a very customised comment layout.

Now, in the functions.php I would like to assign simply with an if statement such as

```
if ( is_last_comment() ) : print "last-comment" endif;
```

I have looked here and in the codex and on other pages and I cannot find anything.

I appreciate anykind of help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use the comments loop(?). If so, you could

#### Possibility A

`count` the comments first, set `$i = 0;` before the loop and `$i++` at the beginning/inside the loop and then attach your needed id when `if ( $count < $i ) $css_id = "id='last-comment'".

#### Possibility B

You could take the comments object(?) and use `$last_comment = count( $comments_obj );` and after the loop `echo $comments->$last_comment;`. If it's an array, you should use `echo $comments[ $last_comment ];` of course.

---

Not sure which one works as I haven't dealt with comments for a while, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your answer kaiser, I do unterstand what your are saying, but it seems pretty much impossible with the already implemented way how I did it. 

To show you my code: http://pastebin.com/Yn0dWxQA

I only get the comment that is currently processed by 

<?php wp_list_comments( array ( 'callback' => 'ipa_comment_template' ) );?>

Well, I dont certainly know that, but that is my explaination of it. As a count($comment) in my ipa_comment_template function always returns a 1. 

I suppose that I need to rethink of the solution that I have now  and propably do it without the functions.php

Comment: @Richard: No, you seem to be on the right track. The only Q is where to get the full comments from. I guess `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->comments` will do it. Maybe you can use a `static $i = 0;` before the loop and then try to count upwards inside your callback with `$i++;` or maybe by reference with `&$i++;`. Give it a try, unmark this A as solution and let's see where we get from here.

Comment: Btw: Have you already done a `var_dump()` of the `$comment` inside your callback? Maybe there's some counter hidden inside the comment object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a way to do it in the comments walker, but if I were approaching the problem I would probably do something like this:

Add a hook on saving a new comment that updates a "latest comment" flag on its parent post;

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'set_last_comment', 10, 2 );

function set_last_comment_flag( $id, $comment ) {
    update_post_meta( $comment->comment_post_ID, '_last_comment', $id );
}
```

and then, use that flag to filter the comment classes.

```
add_filter( 'comment_class', 'flag_last_comment', 10, 4)

function flag_last_comment( $classes, $class, $comment_id, $post_id ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_last_comment', true ) == $comment_id ) 
        $classes[] = 'last_comment';

    return classes;
}
```

Now, this flags the last comment written, not necessarily the bottom one as displayed on the page (you could have threaded comments, or multiple page of comments on a post). So I don't know how well it would work for you.

If you have to target the last comment displayed on the page, I would really just use javascript to apply whatever class you want to it. The logic required to figure that out from the comment walker would probably be a lot more complex than a single line of jQuery to go back after the page has rendered and find the last list item.